# Will (and how) CoreCLR out-of-band libraries have InternalCall and unsafe in untrusted environment?

Tags: .net, security, asp.net-core-mvc, unsafe, coreclr

I know that some performance-critical methods in .NET Framework are implemented via CLR itself for better performance. Also some methods are implemented with unsafe.

Since those NuGet out-of-band libraries provided by Microsoft are local to application and can be updated independently they become a part of user code. But in not full-trusted environment user code can't contain unsafe and how about InternalCalls?

Will CoreCLR out-of-band libraries be slower without these optimizations? Or can they still be performed? But how?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'out of band'? Do you mean 3rd-party libraries, that is, those not provided by Microsoft? Microsoft libraries that use InternalCall/unsafe will be trusted, and thus can be run.

Comment: @antiduh I mean NuGet libraries provided by Microsoft. You can search for "out-of-band" on this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/12/04/introducing-net-core.aspx

Comment: @LexLi CoreCLR is not only for ASP.NET. It's supposed to be used on portable platforms too. Universal Apps do use partial trust.

Comment: Oh, I've just got an idea. They just should sign their assemblies. So simple...